# A question about the ProcessStartInfo class and the Argument Property?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, process, backgroundworker

Some sample code:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "path to update.exe";
psi.Arguments = "arguments for update.exe";
psi.Verb = "runas";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();   
process.WaitForExit();
```

Ref: ***0xA3.***

Programmatically in code what type of objects if possible could you pass into the '.Arguments' property? Typically you can pass an int or a string type. I want to know if you could pass in a more complicated type like a DirectoryInfo[] or a FileInfo[]? Would anyone know if this is possible? If not i'll have to come up with something else?

Why? I am trying to remove some problem code from a very large background worker and the only solution is to pass the data I require into a process that will handle the work I need doing in a completey different process. Problem this problem code always throws up on permissions - permissions the app does not have.

Comment: Why do you need a separate process?

Comment: i am shipping out problem code that needs elevated privileges into a different and seperate .exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Serialize the data then you can "pipe" the resulting string into the other process's standard input. See example of "Process.StandardInput Property" help topic at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx
- Serialize the data, store into a file then have other process read this file, passing the path to the file in Arguments.

<strike>- Allocate the object into global memory then pass the resulting IntPtr, in Arguments, to the other process.</strike>

Comment: Option 2 is exactly what I had in mind as my alternative solution. +1! 
Could elaborate further on option 1 or 3 ???

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz: I update answer with a refernce to sample code that transfers a string to the other process and removed third option because it is too hard.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are exactly what you'd type (with leading and trailing quotes), if you were running the .exe from the command prompt.

Use strings.

Comment: I have come up with my solution. I was over complicated my problem and was being lazy .. i can step further back in code and use a string. I will post my solution very soon.

Answer (score 0):

As defined the [Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) property is of type [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) so you could only pass space delimited arguments to the process the same way you would when calling it at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.

You should consider making a new AppDomain in your existing process.

Comment: I figured as much. It was worth a shot :)